# Can maven or gradle relocate dependencies on import?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I need a way for maven (or if maven doesn't work gradle) to relocate a dependency when importing it in the `<dependencies>` part of my pom.xml

Relocating the dependency when I build my jar doesn't work too well because intellij isn't able to debug the shaded code anymore.

I imagine something like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <relocatedName>shaded.org.projectlombok</relocatedName>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What do you mean by relocate ? To download from web if its not found on your .m2 ?

Comment: If you have two different versions of one dependency you must / might want to shade and relocate one version. This will change the package names at compile time, so they don't conflict. This can change `com.test` to `shaded.com.test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible in Maven.

You can shade a dependency with the Maven shade plugin (this is probably what you meant with "during build"), but you cannot generally shade it.

The only way I would see would be to build the third-party artifact from source with different project names or to do manipulation in the third-party jar itself and republish it to your (local) repository.